# stream list into a set

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am looking to refactor how I have used a stream in some of my code.  The first example is how I currently have done it.  The second example is what im trying to make it look like.

```
Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();

someDao.findByType(type)
            .stream()
            .forEach(t-> result.add(t.getSomeMethodValue()) );
```

Could it look something like this?  If so how do I make it do it?

```
Set<String> results = someDao.findByType(type)
            .stream()
            .collect(  /*  ?? no sure what to put here  */ );
```

Comment: You need to map the Stream elements before collecting them into the Set. `someDao.findByType(type)
            .stream().map(TheClass::getValue).collect(toSet());`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toSet` :

```
Set<String> results = someDao.findByType(type)
        .stream()
        .map(ClassName::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```